# Re-use change address as a receive address

Tags: wallet, address, privacy, address-reuse

Technically speaking, is it possible to reuse a change address from a previous transaction and make it a receive address?

What are the pros and cons of doing so? This does look like a bad privacy practice, but I wonder whether there would be any rationale for doing this.

Are there any wallets that currently support this functionality?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Technically speaking, is it possible to reuse a change address from a previous transaction and make it a receive address?

Technically that would be possible. The network rules have no concept of change or receive addresses - it's just a scriptPubKey that coins are sent to.

> What are the pros and cons of doing so?

I see no reason why you'd want to do that. It's bad for privacy as it's gratuitously exposing linkage between transactions.

> Are there any wallets that currently support this functionality?

I hope not.